# Python: sum values of three or more arrays only at selected indices

Tags: python, arrays

Suppose that I have three tables with two columns (namely, "Time" and "Value"), and I want to store them in different arrays:

```
Time1 = [1,2,5,6,7]
Time2 = [1,2,3,7,8]
Time3 = [1,2,5,7,9]
Value1 = [1,4,2,2,6]
Value2 = [1,3,3,2,5]
Value3 = [1,1,1,1,1]
```

The three "Time" arrays are already in an increasing order. I would like to know the easiest way to compute a fourth couple of arrays with these conditions:

- First one: A new "Time" array with all the elements who are in all three "Time" arrays
- Second one: The sum of the elements in "Value" at the index where elements in the "Time" array matches

Using my example, the ouput would be:

```
Time4 = [1,2,7]
Value4 = [Value1[0]+Value2[0]+Value3[0],Value1[1]+Value2[1]+Value3[1],Value1[4]+Value2[3]+Value3[3]]
```

The easiest way to do it is using a step-by-step check:

```
j = 0
k = 0
for i in range(len(Value1)):
  if Time1[i] == Time2[j] == Time3[k]:
    Time4.append(Time1)
    Value4.append(Value1[i]+Value2[j]+Value3[k])
    j += 1
    k += 1
```

But this would be followed by many condition controls, when the "if" condition doesn't happen. Basically, I should just increment the "right" index until i recover the "if" condition, since "Time" arrays are already in increasing order, ie:

```
elif Time1[i]>Time2[j]:
  if Time1[i]>Time3[k]:
    print 'A value in Time1 is missing'
    j += 1
    k += 1
```

And so on. The situation would get even worse if I have more than 3 arrays to compare. So, is there a easier way to do it?

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

Comment: Look at converting the arrays to sets and then use the intersection operator.

Answer (score 1):

For your `Value` arrays, you'll want to use a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk):

```
Value4 = [Value1[i]+Value2[i]+Value3[i] for i in range(len(Value1))]
```

For your `Time` arrays, you could exploit the [`set`](https://www.python-course.eu/sets_frozensets.php) object.

```
Time4 = list(set(Time1 + Time2 + Time3))
```

This concatenates your existing arrays, converts this concatenated list to a set (which has only unique elements) and then converts back to a list. Note that this will NOT necessarily preserve order, if that matters. If order matters then stepping through is your best bet.

For what it's worth, if you think you're going to end up with more arrays, you should consider having an array of `Time` arrays and an array of `Value` arrays, e.g.

```
Times = [ [1,2,5,6,7], [1,2,3,7,8], [1,2,5,7,9] ]
Values = [ [1,4,2,2,6], [1,3,3,2,5], [1,1,1,1,1] ]
```

This will allow you to more easily generalize the above techniques. Like so:

```
NewValue = [sum([ValList[i] for ValList in Values]) for i in range(len(Values[0]))]

NewTime = set(Times[0])
for TimeList in Times:
   NewTime = NewTime & set(TimeList)
NewTime = list(NewTime)
```

Sadly I couldn't think of a one-line way to get the `Time` array. These will work for any nonzero number of `Time`/`Value` lists. IMPORTANT ASSUMPTIONS: There needs to be at least one `Time` array and at least one `Value` array, and each of these arrays needs to have to same size as each other.

Answer (score 1):

For (1), use sets. They have the big advantage that they only store unique values and many operations are way faster.

```
unique_times = set(Time1) & set(Time2) & set(Time3)
```

Now, `unique_times` will contain all times that occur in all sets (hence the `&`).

For (2), the next step I would take is to find the indices of these times in the original arrays.

```
for time_array, value_array in zip([Time1, Time2, Time3], [Value1, Value2, Value3]):
    time_indices = [idx for idx,time in time_array if time in unique_times]
    values = [value_array[idx] for idx in time_indices]
    total = sum(values)
```

A problem with this is that storing times and values in multiple variables causes that you will have to change the code each time the number of arrays changes. The fact that you use numbers to name different variables indicates that you are repeating yourself, which is never a good idea in coding. So my advice is to find a way to store all times in one multi-dimensional array and all values in another. You'll see that things will be optimized soon.